# Confusion regarding Relative Import in ANTLR

Tags: python, antlr4

I came across this line of code, `if __name__ is not None and "." in __name__:` which is included in some auto-generated files in ANTLR such as ExprParser.py

```
# Generated from Expr.g by ANTLR 4.7.2
from antlr4 import *
if __name__ is not None and "." in __name__:
    from .ExprParser import ExprParser
else:
    from ExprParser import ExprParser
```

From what I have heard `__name__` is automatically set by python, so how can it be `None` and also `__name__` can only consists of module name or string `"__main__"` so how could it contain dot (.). So, isn't this line of code unnecessary or I am missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can it be `None`

To the best of my knowledge, there's no way it could end up `None` under normal circumstances (i.e. outside of the programmer messing with `__name__`'s value), so that check indeed seems redundant.

> can only consists of module name or string `"__main__"` so how could it contain dot (.)

The names of nested modules contain dots, so it's checking whether it's a nested module.

Comment: Okay, Thank you, I have submitted the PR (https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/pull/4222), lets see the developers response.